# What are the x86 instructions that affect ESP as a side effect?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-memory, stack-pointer

I know that `call` and `ret` will modify the value of `esp` and that `push` and `pop` have a number of variants, but are there other instructions that will affect the stack pointer ?

Comment: The instructions `INT` and `INTO` and `IRET` and many others that control that register directly as with other registers, such as `ADD ESP,8`.

Comment: Search volume 2 of Intel's manual for `ESP ←`?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the manuals?

Comment: The manuals are extremely dense and figuring out exactly how to use them to answer a question of that type seems to be out of scope for introduction-level classes (that's the level I'm at). For instance Michael's comment above is helpful on that regard. I believe a "research method" type answer, rather than a list, would be very valuable to me as well as other beginners who might be in the same situation.

Comment: not something we have memorized I would assume we would have to do the same work which is not the point of stackoverflow.  The answer is to look at the documentation for the instruction set, how to make that faster or easier is something you have to sort out.

Comment: who knows maybe someone here has that kind of photographic memory with search capabilities...

Comment: "there is this way of looking for instructions that set a specific register" helps. "RTFM" and "sort it out"are pretty much the opposite of the point of stackoverflow - especially when the manuals in question are > 4500 pages and arguably complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following instructions modify the stack pointer as an implicit operand<sup>1</sup>:

- `call`
- `enter`
- `int n/into/int 3`
- `iret/iretd`
- `leave`
- `pop`
- `push`
- `ret/retf`
- `sysenter`
- `sysexit`
- `pusha`
- `popa`
- `pushf/pushfd/pushfq`
- `popf/popfd/popfq`
- `vmlaunch/vmresume`
- `eexit`

Every instruction that can write an arbitrary general-purpose regiser (like `imul reg, r/m32, imm8` or add / sub) can write ESP if you want, but it's only interesting to list one where the stack pointer is an operand even if you don't mention it explicitly.  I leave to you the burden of telling primary and side effects apart.

Keep in mind that any instruction capable of generating an exception can potentially modify the stack pointer, at least the kernel stack pointer if not user-space.
I've not considered such instructions in order to avoid trivializing your question.

Those are all the instructions I can find by searching the Intel manuals at the time of creation of this answer.
While I did my best scrutinizing the manuals I wouldn't swear to that list.

---

<sup>1</sup> Either `SP`, `ESP` or `RSP`.

Comment: Listing `pusha/pushad` like that is odd because `pusha` (at least for NASM and [my insref based on it](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insPUSHA)) can, depending on the code segment's default bitness, mean either `pushaw` or `pushad` (whichever form it is handled as when occurring without `osize` prefix). Your choice of wording appears to default to 16-bit CS where `pusha` means `pushaw`.

Comment: @ecm MASM also does that IIRC. I use the mnemonics Intel uses in their manuals.

Comment: Re: the footnote: SP vs. ESP vs. RSP is determined by the stack address size in the SS descriptor, right?  I 64-bit is the only option in 64-bit mode, but in protected mode you can have 16-bit address/operand size as the default with a 32-bit stack-address size, I think.  (I guess that's getting a bit off topic for this question.)

Answer (score 3):

The `push(a/ad/f)` and `pop(a/ad/f)` instruction groups are modifying the stack pointer `(e)sp`. Interrupt calls `int` also modify it. The instruction `call` will push the return address to the stack and `ret` removes it. In the form of `ret NUMBER` additionally that number of bytes are removed from the stack to clean it.

Of course you can use `(e)sp` in other instructions, like `mov` or arithmetic instructions like `add` or `sub`. It will be represented in the REG, R/M, or BASE fields in the opcode-byte, modR/M-byte, and/or sib-byte.

Comment: `ENTER`, `LEAVE` are modifying stack pointer too, but it's not exactly "side effect", more like the "main effect".

Comment: @Ped7g: I think the point is having [ER]SP as an *implicit* operand, whether it's the main effect or not.  ESP is one of the 8 general-purpose registers, so every instruction that can write a GPR can modify it, including  weird examples like `imul esp, edx, 1` to set ESP = EDX in a convoluted way.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I once wrote some code that used SP as a scribble register. Clearly interrupts must be disabled to do that.